Finding power rating of stepper motor used as generator
I have a stepper motor that I want to use as a generator for a micro wind turbine project, and I need to know how much power it can generate.
The stepper motor is a 57BYGH420 for Wantai Motor, and it has a rated voltage of 3.6 V and a rated current of 2 A. Does this simply mean that the rated power is 7.2 W when used as a generator? That sounds too low to me. Do the ratings for when it is used as a motor apply when it is used as a generator?
The general question: How do I calculate the power rating of a stepper motor used as a generator?

I'd like to see research or study papers in the topic of using steppers as generators. Start there. Perhaps someone can help you interpret such papers.

If the rated input power is 7.2W, you know the output power will be less than that (due to efficiency losses in the motor). Why do you think 7.2W is too low? Stepper motors aren’t very efficient as a general rule, and then you’ve got losses whatever rectification you’re using to go from the waveform the stepper motor generates to your required output.

It's the maximum power the windings were designed for. So your perceived low is relative.

You need to know the motor's back EMF constant. You can easily measure this by spinning the motor and measuring the phase voltage output or the manufacturer may be able to tell you. You'll also need to know the maximum recommended motor speed. Using this information you'll be able to calculate a rough 'maximum sustainable output power'.
However it's unlikely that this will be the point you'd want to run it at. Due to the way losses are generated in the motor (dominated by iron losses at high speeds), you would need to characterise losses vs RPM vs phase current to find the point that optimises efficiency within the motor's power dissipation limits. This might be higher or lower than the simple calculation above, and you will be able to change it by adding things like motor cooling.
Also remember that this is for one phase, and a stepper motor is a two phase system.
At a rough guess, for a motor like the one you've linked to, I'd expect it to be able to generate upwards of 50-100W.

I have measured the open-circuit one-phase voltage constant to 41 V/kRPM (rms value). The voltage was measured at six different rpms, with the lowest rpm being 100 and the highest 1000. Unfortunately, the specs do not list the maximum speed. As I know the phase resistance and inductance, I think I can do an equivalent circuit analysis to find the optimal load vs rpm, but I struggle to see how I can determine how much power the generator can generate without overheating or taking damage. Your rough guess is more what I was hoping for, though. Thanks.
